# Java - Catch Exception e

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

What does the `e` mean in the following code?

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do something
}
```

I've been researching and have gotten nothing.

`System.out.println("Thanks!");`

Comment: `e` is a reference to the instance of the `Exception`, like `s` would be a reference to an instance of `String` when you declare like `String s = "...";`.  Otherwise you won't be able to reference the exception and learn what's wrong with your code

Comment: @MadProgrammer so it doesn't have to be `e`? Could it be written as some other letter and still work?

Comment: The [Exceptions lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) might provide you with better/more information

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be `e`.  I often use `exp`, but it's kind of a personal thing.  It's just the variable name

Comment: You can name your variables as you please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a variable name. `Exception` is the type. `e` is the name. You can use a different name. You might display a message to the user (or a stack trace).

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch (Exception ohNo) {
    System.out.printf("Caught exception %s doing something.%n", ohNo.toString());
    ohNo.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you please check my question? i think you can help me on exception handling. thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747085/java-try-catch-exception

Answer (score 1):

It is a object which contain info about an error happend.
Inherit from throwable and give you a clear message of why your code went wrong

More info

[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Exception.html)