# Java Try Catch Exception

Tags: java, api, exception, error-handling, try-catch

My current block of codes returns an exception like:

```
Exception occurred in API invocation A1-123 Fatal error
Caused by: A9-001 ColName is not found in TableName
```

but I would like to...

1. get rid of `A1 Exception`
2. show `A9 Exception` directly
3. not show `A9 Exception` in `Caused by`

How do I make the exception look like this?

```
Exception occurred in API invocation A9-001 ColName is not found in TableName
<no Caused by clause>
```

This is my sample code:

```
public Sample Method (Input input) throws AException
{
   con = getSQLConnection();

   try{
      //do something
      if(x==null){
         throw new AException(A9ErrorMessages.A9_ERROR_FROM_TABLE, new String [] { "ColName", "TableName"});
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e){
      logger().error(e);
      throw new AException(e);
   }
   finally{
      if(con!=null){
         try{
            con.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            logger().error(e);
            throw new AException(e);  
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Would it work if it's something like this:

```
   try{
      //do something
   }
   catch (Exception e){
      logger().error(e);
      throw new AException(A9ErrorMessages.A9_ERROR_FROM_TABLE, new String [] { "ColName", "TableName"});
   }
   catch (Exception e){
      logger().error(e);
      throw new AException(e);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the error that you want to catch and pass on is an `AException` - otherwise what you're asking for would violate the contract of the method.  You could achieve what you're wanting with an extra `catch` clause like this.

```
try {
    // whatever
}
catch (AException ae) {
    throw ae;
}
catch (Exception e){
  logger().error(e);
  throw new AException(e);
}
finally {
     // whatever
}
```

That way, only exceptions that are not already of type `AException` will get wrapped in new `AException` objects.

Comment: i am new to try-catch. you mean to say that my current first catch should be treated as second catch then i create a new first catch. but how do i exactly implement `throw new exception AException(A9Messages.A9_ERROR_FROM_TABLE, new String [] { "ColName", "TableName"})` in the first catch? (i dont understand this form: `catch (AException ae) { throw ae; }` )

Answer (score 0):

the first commenter is correct. i was able to do it by creating a new first catch:

```
public Sample Method (Input input) throws AException
{
   con = getSQLConnection();

   try{
      //do something
      if(x==null){
         AException ae = new AException(A9ErrorMessages.A9_ERROR_FROM_TABLE, new String [] { "ColName", "TableName"});
         logger().error(ae);
         throw ae;
      }
   }
   catch (AException ae){
      logger().error(ae);
      throw ae;
   }
   catch (Exception e){
      logger().error(e);
      throw new AException(e);
   }
   finally{
      if(con!=null){
         try{
            con.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            logger().error(e);
            throw new AException(e);  
         }
      }
   }
}
```